# java.io.FileNotFoundException:<file_path>/<file_name>(No such file or directory)

Tags: spring, spring-batch

This is a spring batch application and I am trying to put values in an excel sheet but it is failing in creating the file.
I have a code, where I am using a writer to write data into an excel sheet, but after writing also, this error comes up:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
<path_name>/AJI.xls (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:188)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:154)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:212)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:203)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:136)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:313)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:144)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable.run(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:275)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Writer Code:

```
  @Override
        public void write(List<? extends DialogTelekom> list) throws Exception {
            /*FILE_NAME +  ApplicationConstants.MULTICHOICE_FILE_START_NAME + 

             ApplicationConstants.UNDERSCORE + 
            LocalDate.now().plusDays(Long.parseLong(startDayOffset)).toString().replaceAll("-","")+ */
                outputFilename = FILE_NAME+"AJI" + ".xls";
                List<Samples> sortedDialogs = new ArrayList<>();
            if (list.size() > 0) {
    
    
                for (Object items : list) {
                    for (Samples myDialog : (List<Samples>) items) {
    
                        sortedDialogs.add(myDialog);
                    }
    
                }
    
            }
            writeToExcel(outputFilename, sortedDialogs);
        }
    
    
    
        private void writeToExcel(String outputFilename , List<Samples> Sample)/* , String chCode*/ throws IOException {
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            currRow = 0;
            // sheet = workbook.createSheet("Channel" + item.getId());
            sheet = workbook.createSheet("AJI");
    
            //sheet.createFreezePane(0, 3, 0, 3);
            sheet.setDefaultColumnWidth(20);
            initDataStyle();
            Row topRow = sheet.createRow(currRow);
            //TODO:
            sheet=workbook.getSheet("AJI");
            System.out.println(Sample.size());
            System.out.println(Sample.toString());
            currRow++;
            addHeaders(sheet, HEADERSProgram, currRow);
            for(Samples mySample : Sample){
                Row programRow = sheet.createRow(currRow);
    
                // TIME
                createStringCell(programRow, Sample.getTime().toString(), 0);
    
                // TITLE
                createStringCell(programRow, Sample.getTitle(), 1);
    
                // DURATION
                createNumericCell(programRow, Sample.getDuration() != null ? Long.valueOf(Sample.getDuration()) : null, 2);
    
                // EPISODE TITLE
                createStringCell(programRow, Sample.getEpisode_Title() != null ? Sample.getEpisode_Title():null, 3);
    
                // SYNOPSIS
                createStringCell(programRow, Sample.getSnyopsis()  != null ? Sample.getSnyopsis():null, 4);
    
                // CATEGORY
                createStringCell(programRow, Sample.getCategory() != null ? Sample.getCategory() : null, 5);
    
                // SYNOPSYS
                createStringCell(programRow, Sample.getType(), 6);
    
                // CONTENT
                createStringCell(programRow, Sample.getContent(), 7);
    
                currRow++;
    
            }
    
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFilename);
            workbook.write(fos);
            fos.close();
    
        }
```

I have checked with debugger, It shows the correct for all the variables, still it is not creating the file. Can u help?

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear that the path is not found; the file is not where the path points. Looks like the path is "<path_name>/AJI.xls" which clearly is wrong since it contains angle brackets. Seems that FILE_PATH is "<path_name>". I don't know what FILE_PATH is supposed to be, but I can say that you need to set FILE_PATH to the file's directory path ... not the string "<path_name>"

Comment: The path is something like : file: ${file_path}/${file_name}, and this values are picked from the application.properties file. the path <path_name> is something I wrote that it is not the exact value, just a variable which can be modified from application.prop

Comment: the path <path_name> is something I wrote that it is not the exact value, just a variable which can be modified from application.prop. Actual path does not contain angle brackets.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to filepath and not having any relation on spring batch. Please advise are you using a custom writer and passing filepath from the bean or its a static variable in code.

Comment: I am adding the path variable as a property in the bean.

Comment: Injecting path property with the @Value annotation and pass to your writer. In the batch configuration you can pass like this @Value("${files.path}")
 private String resourcesPath;
 @Value("${files.error.path}")
 private String errorPath;

Comment: MoveFilesTasklet moveFilesTasklet = new MoveFilesTasklet();
  try {
   moveFilesTasklet.setSourcePath(resourcesPath);
   moveFilesTasklet.setResourcesPath(sucessPath);
   moveFilesTasklet.setResources(
     new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("file:" + sucessPath + fileType));